# Esta pregunta es ambigua?

Tags: ambigüedad

La pregunta es:

¿Cuáles son el valor medio y la desviación estándar del
número de proyectos que no están entre estos primeros 15
que son de la segunda sección?

Del problema:

Pienso que se puede interpretar como:

1. Que no están dentro de los 15 y que además son de la segunda sección.
2. Que no son de la segunda sección pero que están dentro de los 15.

Por si les parece relevante, la pregunta proviene del enunciado:

> Un instructor que impartió dos secciones de estadística de ingeniería
> el semestre pasado, la primera con 20 estudiantes y la segunda con 30,
> decidió asignar un proyecto semestral. Una vez que todos los proyectos
> le fueron entregados, el instructor los ordenó al azar antes de
> calificarlos. Considere los primeros 15 proyectos calificados.

Answer (score 1):

Pregunta: ¿Cuáles son el valor medio y la desviación estándar del número de proyectos que no están entre estos primeros 15 que son de la segunda sección?

Posibles interpretaciones:

1. Que no están dentro de los 15 **y** que además son de la segunda sección.
2. Que no están dentro de los 15 **que son** de la segunda sección.

En (1), las dos relativas están yuxtapuestas, como cuando digo:

- Busco respuestas que no estén entre las mejores que hayan sido entregadas en la segunda tanda (= Busco respuestas que no estén entre las mejores Y que hayan sido entregadas en la segunda tanda)

En (2), la segunda relativa restringe a la primera:

- Busco respuestas que no estén entre las mejores que hayan sido entregadas en la segunda tanda (= Busco respuestas que no estén entre aquellas mejores que fueron entregadas en la segunda tanda)

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry my written Spanish is not good enough to answer except in English

> ¿Cuáles son el valor medio y la desviación estándar del número de proyectos que no están entre estos primeros 15 que son de la segunda sección?

I think there is a word missing

> ¿Cuáles son el valor medio y la desviación estándar del número de proyectos que no están entre estos primeros 15 y que son de la segunda sección?

So that would imply that your option 1

> Que no están dentro de los 15 y que además son de la segunda sección.

is the correct one.

But you might confirm this with the instructor in the class from which it comes.

Answer (score 0):

La ambigüedad surge porque la pregunta está mal formulada, ya que ambas aclaraciones "que..." no dejan claro a quién se refieren.

No obstante, de acuerdo al contexto del problema enunciado y la situación azarosa que plantea, la única interpretación que tiene sentido podría escribirse así:

*¿Cuáles son el valor medio y la desviación estándar del número de proyectos de la segunda sección que no están entre estos primeros 15?*

Aún así, más allá de lo longüístico, tiene poco sentido la pregunta en sí misma. Porque ese número de proyectos es una única cantidad en particular (además, desconocida), por lo que resulta ridículo tratar estadísticamente un solo valor.